# Lambert Pairwise Sums O(n^2), X+Y Sorting

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, open-problem

Sorting Pairwise Sums of X+Y with O(n^2) comparisons is a hard problem: [http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P41.html](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Eorourke/TOPP/P41.html)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%2B_Y_sorting

It seems Lambert has concluded that if some non-comparison operations are allowed, then it is achievable.

I can find his original paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759290089X

Additionally, I found a [functional](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZQJnYoAmw6gC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=Lambert%20algorithm%20Pairwise%20Sums&source=bl&ots=7A8zvCOtzG&sig=KxUV2oP6MKttANp-tdgmetcSw7s&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JC-5VJL6OsGyUcWwg8gH&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Lambert%20algorithm%20Pairwise%20Sums&f=false) approach for his algorithm.

However, I really don't understand how the algorithm works, even after several attempts.

What I know so far about how the algorithm works:

1. tag element with its original index
2. negate it
3. using the equation of x - y < x' - y' == x - x' < y - y'.
   Other than that I am lost.

Does anyone here really understand that algorithm? Can anyone clearly explain it in a simple way, and particularly how we use step 3 above?